Excel VBA & IE : Input value to a prompt popup and enter
In short:
How do you 1. Focus on a prompt popup on IE, 2. Type in a value, and 3. Return?
In Long:
Hi,
I am trying to automate a login/file-downloading process on a company intranet server through VBA. I have gotten the log-in and navigating working, however am stuck on trying to download a file from the site.
The 'Download' works as follows:

When the 'Download' button is clicked, 'createFileForDownload' is triggered
Then the user is prompted to input a string
If there is no input, or if you click "cancel" on the popup it alerts an error message
If there is a valid input, it begins to compile a file and downloads it to the PC

CODE :
function createFileForDownload(){
    // Main function triggered when the 'Download' button is clicked
    var reason = getReasonForDownload();
    if (reason){
        //Retrieve data from server and create the file for downloading
    }
}

function getReasonForDownload(inputName){
    // The function I cannot get past
    var reasonForDownload = prompt("Specify the reason for your download", "");
    if (reasonForDownload  && reasonForDownload .length > 0) {
        return "<input type='hidden' name='" + inputName + "' value='" + reasonForDownload  +"'>";
    } else {
        alert("You must input a value");
        closeHiddenWaitingFrame();
        $('.waitingPop').removeClass("open"); //Close the waiting frame
        return false;
    }
}

PROBLEM:
However, when I try to access the prompt, it pauses the running VBA code.
Is there any way I could input a string to the prompt and 'enter'?
What I have attempted so far:
SendKeys

only runs after the prompt is shown, and I am unable to change focus to the prompt without clicking it manually

Overwriting the OnClick method

I cannot override the enter onclick function, because the function itself contains the code to actually construct the file for downloading.
I was hoping there would be a way to overwrite the 'getReasonForDownload' function and return it, however it seems I would have to rewrite the entire 'createFileForDownload' function to achieve what I want.

Sorry about the lack of info; I cannot post the actual site or code online due to the company's privacy issues.
Any help would be greatly appreciated: thank you so much in advance!

If you can't show the relevant VBA part (how IE is connected to Excel) and the markup structure, we can only speculate with the solution. Notice, that it looks like there's no actual focusable "prompt"  window on the page, it's just a div or some other element emulating a prompt window. You could just set the value of the "reason" input element, and dispatch a click event to the OK button.
